# creating A simple Reminder Application in Android

Tags: android

I want to build up  a small Android application that can remind us of any event/Task we mark on it. It can be like reminding us about a meeting, time to pay any bill etc.
The app can take from the user the event name, date and time of the event. Store the details to the database and alert the user 10 min before the event.

I am new in android development.Please give me some idea to create this application.

Comment: This is not the place for tutorials or how-to guides. I suggest that you use Google to find a tutorial on creating a todo list app for Android. Then come back to Stack Overflow when you have specific programming questions.

Comment: Try some thing and come with the Issues so that ppl may help u:)

Comment: @Blundell I making the Reminder app using your tutorial, but it seems like not the latest. Do you have the updated version ? Thanks